# How to make weekday names uppercased and what to change to just show 5 weeks in every month in FSCalendar?

Tags: fscalendar

I want my calendar's weeknames in uppercase form and also want to show just 5 week, as there can be maximum 31 days, so no need of 6 weeks, just wasting some space. It will be helpful if anyone can show me the right direction?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 5 week?

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you mean with 5 weeks month (i had the same problem at first). Fortunately, the library is pretty flexible so all you have to do is set the property `placeholderType` to `.None`. In my case, my calendar *outlet* is called `calendarOutlet` so the line of code looks like this:

`calendarOutlet.placeholderType = .None`

As for *weeknames* you'll have to be more specific than that because in my case the calendar **always** has shown the weekdays in uppercase (see image below).

[image]